# Spring JPA - require JDBC and Hibernate Jar's on class path

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

Am new to the spring frameworks ,Iam planning to create a Spring Rest application with JPA . am using Mysql database .

I have downloaded the Spring initializer with Web and JPA as dependdencies with Maven. but while Maven install am getting error asking for MYSQL connector jar , so  i have adde the maven enetry for the same , on the second try it asking for the hibernate jar .

So am confused like what is the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency doing ? if we need to add the jars into class path , then what is the use of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa ?

Answer (score 0):

`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is a combination of Spring Boot, which itself consists of the Spring framework core and is meant for rapid stand-alone application development, and Spring Data JPA which is Spring's own opinionated abstraction of JPA. It's basically just an interface with a few convenience classes, you still need to supply the JDBC driver for the corresponding database (MySQL in your case) and an actual ORM implementation (the layer that translates your database rows to Java objects and gives you CRUD functionality).

Comment: Thanks rorschach for make me clear about the concept